# Nginx + PHPBB3 reverse proxy images problem

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, images, phpbb

Hello all I have a problem with my Nginx Frontend + Apache2 backend + PHPBB3 software. It doesn't load the CSS and the images neither.
I get constant errors like these:

> 2010/04/14 16:57:25 [error] 13365#0: *69 open() "/var/www/foo/styles/styles/coffee_time/theme/large.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 83.44.175.237, server: www.foo.com, request: "GET /styles/coffee_time/theme/large.css HTTP/1.1", host: "www.foo.com", referrer: "http://www.foo.com/viewforum.php?f=43"

This is my config of the site:

> server {
>           listen   80;
>           server_name  www.foo.com;
>           access_log  /var/log/nginx/foo.access.log;

```
    # serve static files directly
    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
    access_log        off;
    expires           30d;
    root  /var/www/foo/;
    }



    location / {
            root   /var/www/foo/;
            index  /var/www/foo/index.php;
    }

   # proxy the PHP scripts to predefined upstream .apache.        #
    location ~ .php$ {
            proxy_pass   http://apache;
   }

    location /styles/ {
            root   /var/www/foo/styles/;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It was kinda noob-problem, wrong paths :)